# FreeType2 Crash on FT_Init_FreeType in xcode(cocos2dx)

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x, freetype

I'm currently trying to learn how to use the FreeType2 library for drawing fonts with OpenGL. However, when I start the program it immediately crashes with the following error: problem loading file 'file name', this will crash in FT_Init_FreeType in xcode(cocos2dx).

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

class ttf_file
{
public:
    std::string filename;
    FT_Library library;
    FT_Error error;

    ttf_file( std::string fname )
    {
        filename = fname;
        error = FT_Init_FreeType( &library );

        if (error) {
            std::cerr << "problem loading file " << filename << "\n";
            exit(1);
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Looks to me as the result of passing in the uninitialized FT_Library variable named library. I would assume that FT_Library has to be initialized first so it can be used by FT_Init_FreeType - unless library is supposed to be an out pointer (it FT_Init_FreeType creates and assigns FT_Library to the pointer passed in).

Comment: You can check the error number, convert it to hexidecimal number and check in the fterrdef.h the error message. There's probably an easier way to do it. :D